# passing argument 1 of 'addObject:' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using the ABAddressbook.I have created ABRecordref.I would like to add it to a mutable array.It is added successfully.But there is a warning

### warning is

passing argument 1 of 'addObject:' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Let me know the reason for this warning and Kindly give me the solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code for this?  It'll be easier to tell what's happening if we can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABRecordRef is not an objc type. it is an opaque type, typedeffed as `void*`.

in these cases, you must cast it to an appropriately compatible type. for example, NSString and CFString are toll free bridged - it is safe to cast them to their ns/cf equivalents.

the documentation states that `ABRecordRef` is toll free bridged with `ABRecord`, so you'd write this:

```
ABRecordRef record = MONGetTheRecord(arg);
[array addObject:(ABRecord*)record];
...
```

in order to correctly typecast it to an objc type (which `addObject:` takes as its argument).